# How to use json with typescript interfaces?

Tags: json, typescript

I am reading JSON data in my typescript app. I found this tool [JSON2TS](http://json2ts.com/) that creates interfaces from JSON, so that typescript knows what the json must contain.

My json:

```
{
"questions": [
    {
    "text": "Is this a question?",
    "answers": ["yes", "no", "maybe", "maybe not"],
    "correct":1
    }]
}
```

The generated interfaces:

```
declare module namespace {

export interface Question {
    text: string;
    answers: string[];
    correct: number;
}

export interface RootObject {
    questions: Question[];
}

}
```

These interfaces need to be saved in a d.ts file and referenced in the code. My question: how do I actually use the json data after loading it with ajax?

Comment: I'm not sure about what you ask for. If you have an object that you get from some ajax-service, you have access to all its properties and methods as usual. All these interfaces are doing is to give you the ability to type it properly.

Comment: Yes, but typescript won't allow that if you don't declare the type. Of course, you can always use "any" as the type, but then you don't have the IDE advantages (code completion and error checking)

Comment: Aha, so your question was how to type your json-object, not how to use the json data.

Comment: Choosing the right wording when you don't know what the exact problem is can sometimes be tricky...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With that definition file, if your code is in the `namespace` namespace, you could do it like this:

```
var questions = <RootObject>functionThatReturnsYourJSONData().questions;
```

If your code is not in the `namespace` namespace, this should work.

```
var questions = <namespace.RootObject>functionThatReturnsYourJSONData().questions;
```

In either case, this would be strongly typed:

```
if (questions.length > 0) {
    console.log(questions[0].text);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! Also, is the "RootObject" really necessary ?

Comment: If the function that returns your data is already typed as a `RootObject`, then no.  I think RootObject is an artifact of the JSON typer you were using.